# Conditional where statement in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, case, where-clause

I've got a table that returns the history of a value, as well as the current one, each with a date.

The oldest date is the main record.  If the value is changed, a new record is created, with the old value, and the main record is updated with the new value.  If this happens again, a third record is created, which contains the now old value.

So if the value starts at 4, changes to 2, then again changes to 1.  The records will go

```
1
4
2
```

I'm currently creating an inner join on the table to itself as follows, which gets the max date of the 3 above records, which would be 2.. The actual value I need is the 4.  The easiest way to tell if a record is a historical one is that the TriageEndDateTime is NULL.

```
INNER JOIN (SELECT EmergencyAttendanceId,MIN(SourceCreateDateTime) as Max_Date
                FROM FactEmergencyAttendanceTriageDetail 
                GROUP BY EmergencyAttendanceId) AS EAiD 
                ON EAiD.EmergencyAttendanceId = FactEmergencyAttendanceTriageDetail.EmergencyAttendanceId
                AND EAiD.Max_Date = FactEmergencyAttendanceTriageDetail.SourceCreateDateTime
```

What I need to do is select the second record, but only if it exists.  So something along the lines of this.

```
 SELECT EmergencyAttendanceId,MIN(SourceCreateDateTime) as Max_Date
    FROM FactEmergencyAttendanceTriageDetail 
    WHERE IF COUNT(EmergencyAttendanceId) > 1 THEN TriageEndDateTime Is NULL ELSE NOT NULL
    GROUP BY EmergencyAttendanceId 
    inside the INNER JOIN.
```

Can anyone help me with this?

### Sample data

[image]

In the above case, record 2 is the one I'm after.

Comment: Sample data and sample resulting rows expected from data sample would be a great point to start from. This is often clearer for the ones reading the question than explaning widely the actual objective. An image is worth a thousand words!

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you need the oldest record to come out, right?

Comment: No, thats the kicker.. Its the first historical record thats created..  See the picture in the edit.  In that case, the 2 was the original value, then changed to a 1, then changed to a 2 again

Comment: It sounds like you want the second record above, but with the first record's SourceCreateDateTime.  Is that correct?

Comment: I don't care about the dates.. I'm just after the 2 from the second record.. The dates are used to order the records, and to join back into my main select query.  See the first INNER JOIN, that needs to bring back the second record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    SELECT EmergencyAttendanceId


    case when count(EmergencyAttendanceId) > 1 then
          MIN
          (
          case when TriageDateTime is null then SourceCreateDateTime end 
          ) 
    else
          min(SourceCreateDateTime)
    end as max_date


    FROM FactEmergencyAttendanceTriageDetail 
    GROUP BY EmergencyAttendanceId
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `CASE` in place of your pseudo-code:

```
WHERE TriageEndDateTime = 
    CASE WHEN EmergencyAttendanceId > 1 THEN NULL ELSE NOT NULL END
```

Comment: +1 Too simple to be true! I just can't understand how I didn't come up with this! Nice one! =)

Comment: I'm getting a few errors with this. the first is Msg 8133, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
None of the result expressions in a CASE specification can be NULL.

Comment: The Second is Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 24
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'NOT'.