# Sql Server Where Case Then Is Null Else Is Not Null

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, case

I have a procedure which receive a bit variable called `@FL_FINALIZADA`.

If it is null or false I want to restrict my select to show only the rows that contain null `DT_FINALIZACAO` values. Otherwise I want to show the rows containing not null `DT_FINALIZACAO` values.

Something like this:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    MyTable 
WHERE 
    ...
    AND
    (
        OPE.DT_FINALIZACAO = (
            CASE
                WHEN (@FL_FINALIZADA <> 1)
                    THEN NULL
                END
        ) OR 
        OPE.DT_FINALIZACAO IS NOT NULL
    )
```

In this case I receive the message:

> None of the result expressions in a
>   `CASE` specification can be `NULL`.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Im not sure why you need the case statement at all in this example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    MyTable 
WHERE
    (ISNULL(@FL_FINALIZADA, 0) = 0
     AND
     OPE.DT_FINALIZACAO IS NULL
     )
     OR
     (@FL_FINALIZADA = 1
      AND
      OPE.DT_FINALIZACAO IS NOT NULL
     )
```

Comment: Non-null values will show up even if you pass `NULL` or `FALSE`.

Comment: Somehow related to my recent answer :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495974/conditional-where-statement-in-t-sql/4496234#4496234

Comment: I got to something similar after spending some hours in the wrong direction. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Change the AND to be:

```
AND (((@FL_FINALIZADA <> 1) AND (OPE.DT_FINALIZACAO IS NULL)) OR ( (@FL_FINALIZADA = 1) AND (OPE.DT_FINALIZACAO IS NOT NULL)))
```

If the bit flag is 1 then DT_FINALIZACAO can't be null.

Comment: this will return null and non values when @FL_FINALIZADA is 0

Comment: is a `NULL` is passed, the query will return an empty resultset

Answer (score 0):

```
IF @FL_FINALIZADA IS NULL
    SET @FL_FINALIZADA = 0

SELECT * FROM NewsletterSubscribers 
WHERE
   (@FL_FINALIZADA = 0 AND OPE.DT_FINALIZACAO IS NULL) 
   OR 
   (@FL_FINALIZADA = 1 AND OPE.DT_FINALIZACAO IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score -4):

My detailed SQL is a little rusty, but have you tried using 0 insted of NULL? I would expect 0 to evaluate the same as NULL in that select